# How to run bash script when a program open in liunx

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, cron

Is there a way to execute bash script when I click a program like NetBeans or DropBox on Ubuntu 
and execute a bash script when exit it

My idea create bash script on cronjob @reboot check every second if the program exist in the current processes

```
#!/bin/bash
NameOfprogram="NetBeans"
while [[ true ]]; do
    countOfprocess=$(ps -ef |grep $NameOfprogram | wc -l)
    if [[ $countOfprocess -gt 1 ]]; then
        #execute bash 
    fi
    sleep 1
done
```

But I think this idea not the best ,Is there a better way to achieve it?

Comment: This sounds like the attempted bad solution for an easy problem...

Comment: `while [[ true ]]` is a check to see if the string "true" is empty. It works for an infinite loop, but shows some confusion on how `[[` works. `while [[ false ]]` would have the same results. `while true` executes the built-in `true`.

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams any better solution ??

Comment: Not without knowing what the actual problem is.

Comment: if you are saying it's a bad solution, what is the best solution ?

Comment: Give a complete, practical example of what you are trying to do.

Comment: I Want to write bash to execute this: when I open NetBeans check in all files from Team Foundation Server and when close NetBeans checkout all files

Answer (score 2):

A better approach is to wrap the executable in a script. That means you put a script with the name of the program in your path (probably `$HOME/bin`) and Linux will use that instead of the real executable.

Now you can execute the real program using:

```
/usr/bin/NetBeans "$@"
```

So to execute the real executable, you just put the absolute path in front of the name. The odd `"$@"` too pass on any arguments someone might have given the script.

Put a loop around this:

```
while [[ true ]]; do
    /usr/bin/NetBeans "$@"
done
```

But there is a problem: You can't exit this program anymore. As soon as you try, it restarts. So if you just want a restart when it crashes:

```
while [[ true ]]; do
    /usr/bin/NetBeans "$@" && exit 0
done
```

As long as the program exits because of an error, it will be restarted. If you quit it, the script will stop.